# Concrete Implementation vs Interface naming conventions

Tags: class, interface, repository, clean-architecture

So i have been doing a little bit of investigating about interface vs concrete implementation naming conventions and i haven't seen any consensus. Some devs use the `Impl` `Imp` prefix or suffix for the concrete implementation and leave the Interface without any prefix or suffix ... mean while other devs use an `I` prefix or suffix to denote the Interface and they leave the concrete implementation without any prefix or suffix.

For example: `interface UserRepository` and class `UserRepositoryImpl: UserRepository`

vs

`interface IUserRepository` and `class UserRepository: IUserRepostiory`

which version is better or is there a better alternative?

My question also applies to `LocalDataSource` and `RemoteDataSource` interface vs concrete implementation naming.